# varnish 5 multile domains

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I followed the tutorial here https://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.1/users-guide/vcl-separate.html

and I need the script 
vcl.load il_1 /etc/varnish/il.vcl

vcl.load co_1 /etc/varnish/cor.vcl

vcl.label l_il il_1

vcl.label l_cor cor_1

vcl.load top_1 /etc/varnish/top.vcl

vcl.use top_1

to load at startup, I replaced the default.vcl in varnish param. with top.vcl but did not work

Comment: or do I need to run these commands only once into varnishadm

Answer (score 0):

The approach with VCL labels to load website specific configuration is not so elegant. It requires you to use a multitude of `if` statements in your main VCL file.

Thus, you might better look at [configuring Varnish virtual hosts](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/varnish-virtual-hosts). That seems to be a more clean and elegant way to define website specific VCL code.